# What is sh in the accessibility permissions in Catalina?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, privacy, accessibility

Not sure what this is, but I upgraded from High Sierra and it asked me to enable it.  This isn't on my Macbook Pro running Catalina.

[image: screenshot]

How can I tell if this is needed?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need it so remove all things there you don’t positively trust and know you need. Then, wait for a dialog to pop up asking again for permissions so you can scrutinize what and why you’re giving up control of your Mac.

In this case, the `sh` process can run all sorts of scripts so it’s like putting a wedge in the door, anyone that uses the wedge can now get in. You’ll only know they used the wedge and not which script or program invoked the wedge.

> Accessibility
>
> Shows apps that run scripts and system commands to control your Mac. Deselect the app if you want to prevent it from controlling your Mac.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh32356/10.14/mac/10.14.5

```
>>> which sh
/bin/sh
```

```
>>> man sh
...
 bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell
...
Bash  is  an  sh-compatible  command language interpreter that executes
       commands read from the standard input or from a file.  Bash also incor-
       porates useful features from the Korn and C shells (ksh and csh).

       Bash  is  intended  to  be a conformant implementation of the Shell and
       Utilities portion  of  the  IEEE  POSIX  specification  (IEEE  Standard
       1003.1).  Bash can be configured to be POSIX-conformant by default.
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if it has something to do with the other issue that appeared at the same time, though not sure it's related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379974/apple-watch-stopped-unlocking-after-catalina-install-how-can-i-fix-it