# Apple watch stopped unlocking due to Chrome Remote Desktop's screen sharing

Tags: macos, google-chrome, catalina, apple-watch, screen-sharing

I think I found the culprit - Chrome Remote Desktop - but is there a way to fix it? Even though it's not actively running (i.e. a remote connection),  I get this on the lock screen:

[image: screenshot 1]

With the little binoculars in the top right:

[image: screenshot 2]

When I uninstall Chrome Remote Desktop it will unlock again with the watch. I feel like perhaps I'm not doing something right because it didn't do this on Mojave.

Why is my screen being shared even when it's not active?

(Additional note: I also have [Screens Connect](https://edovia.com/en/screens-connect/) actively running without issue -> I can still unlock the mac with the watch, and the binoculars do not appear on the lock screen. It's definitely something going on with Chrome Remote Desktop)

Comment: which apps have permission to "screen recording" in sys pref > security and privacy > privacy ? Also, take a look at sys pref > sharing > screen sharing.

Comment: Team Viewer is there currently with no issues unlocking with the watch. And the screen sharing is active in the preferences (it's been active for many years without any issues - never made any changes there). When i have Chrome Remote Desktop installed, it does show up in Screen Recording. It's as if it's always open and 'on' - i get it to accept incoming connections, but why is the screen being 'shared'? That should only happen after a connection is opened?

Comment: **1** then you can write a script which turns on and off the screen sharing in sys pref, and demands from you the password when it clicks on the padlock. **2** You should install the app, and check its internal settings if such a checkbox is ticked.

Comment: Whatever Chrome RD is doing, it's hooking a system call, at all times, for screen sharing.  I don't use Chrome mainly because it's a resource hog, but this seems to be a huge security hole.  I'd avoid this tool.

Comment: I've had the exact same issue start today, after having Chrome Remote Desktop installed for months. Was there an update to Chrome Remote Desktop?

Comment: I can’t find a change log for it. I’m almost positive this wasn’t happening yesterday... I woke the Mac up many times with the watch.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting a comment as an answer to the main question, but unfortunately it appears I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment.

Anyway, I just wanted to point out that *there was* indeed an update on Chrome RD side: to be sure, I checked current version (80.0.3987) of /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/ChromeRemoteDesktopHost.app and went into Time Machine to compare with the version I had before a couple of days ago (78.0.3904).

Also, I remember that a few days ago that I was asked to enable some Privacy settings in the Preference Pane when the update passed -- and I did so as instructed by some Google-looking GUI that appeared at start-up. I think they were 'Accessibility' and 'Screen recording'.

Since the update, I too have been experiencing the very same symptoms: that is, unlocking with Apple Watch stopped working.

HTH

Sergio

Comment: We’re you able to restore the older version and see if it had the same issue?

Comment: Honestly I am not really willing to try. I am a bit afraid that restoring only the previous version of the .app would not be so healty for my Mac. And I wouldn't know exactly which files should be rolled back as well. Something in the Pref Pane also change. Finally, I must say that I have few doubts. The day before the automatic update, it worked. The day after, it did not.

Comment: I’m thinking more people will have this issue as they realize the update took place and it stopped unlocking. Hopefully google will release a fix soon. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: U welc. That’s my hope as well, even though I’m not sure whether there are many people out there who use both CRD and Watch unlock at the same time. And that have the tech insight to realize that an update in CRD is the problem. So I have hope, but little. I sent Google a feedback on the web client home page of RD. But it seems I sent it into a black hole. No answer so far - not even an automatic response.

Comment: Btw, it looks to me as though Google changed something structural in their server software, for instance now requiring user consent in Pref Pane — maybe they aligned their software to Apple standards in terms of security and privacy? So I’m thinking that rolling back could be difficult for them. Would be nice if they at least allowed one to enable / disable server software easily, without having to install / uninstall. This way one could just enable it when it is really needed.